# How to run an interior gas (LP) line

Tags: plumbing, gas, propane

I need to run a gas (LP) line from outside the house to a cooktop in the kitchen. Here's what I *think* I need to do:

1. drill a hole in the exterior wall and the header (from the attic) of the same wall
2. connect a 90° joint to Corrugated Stainless Steel Tubing (CSST), drop it through the hole drilled in the header and fish it through the hole in the exterior wall
3. connect a short piece of black pipe to the elbow, and connect it to the regulator installed by the propane supplier
4. the other end of the CSST would run through the attic and down through another hole in the header of the kitchen wall
5. connect to cooktop (I will, of course, use the supplied conversion kit)

This is the plan I've assimilated from research, much of it conflicting. So I'm sure it needs some adjustments. Here are my questions:

1. from what I've read CSST is the way to go, but how do you protect it from fasteners going into the wall?
2. I assumed short legs of black pipe should be used at the ends, since it probably looks better coming out of the wall, unless...is there some kind of wall plate/jack that could be used?

Is this approach generally sound? Anything else I should consider?

Comment: You may want to consider contacting a [pipefitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipefitter), since working with gas can be hazardous to your health.

Comment: Isn't the DIY ethos _if a pro can do it, so can I_?

Comment: I think the exception to that, is when you can easily blow your house up because of a tiny mistake.

Comment: If it's any solace, this will be done prior to the propane tank being set up, and the propane company has said they'll run an end-to-end test at that time.

Comment: That's a LOT of solace.

Comment: I'm marking bib's as the answer since it comes the closest to actually addressing my question. I can't help but think there's a lot of FUD about propane out there. These [propane facts](http://www.propanecouncil.org/what-is-propane/facts/) from the PERC make it seem pretty safe.

Comment: In my county we can not use corrugated / flex line in the walls black pipe only inside no poly ethier. Also the entry to the home requires a listed "bulkhead" flange ( a flange welded to the pipe that attaches to the structure).  My county is very strict on these items and the pressure test, most inspectors want 30 psi on the gauge at the start of the inspection and no movement by the end , I usually leave it overnight if no change things are good since this is over 10x the normal pressure after the regulator for a residential system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corrugated pipe is generally intended only to be used as the last connection to an appliance, in a living space where it not vulnerable to banging or jostling (usually behind or in a space at the bottom of an appliance), but where it can be seen and accessed if work is being done.  It is not intended to be buried in a wall, where it could be pierced by a random fastener driven blindly.

It is also only used where an appliance needs to be moved to connect or disconnect it to the supply line. In all other cases and places, solid black pipe should be used, not corrugated. Solid should be run to the connection right before the stove, a cutoff valve should be installed at that point before attaching a short length of corrugated between the stove and the valve.

Having said all this, I join in the various suggestions that you engage a professional plumber (pipefitter). I know how to do it, I have done it in the past, and I would NOT do it again. The risks are *very* high, and a simple oversight (common to many a DIYer) is disastrous. The pros avoid those oversights because of long practice.

Please stay safe.

Comment: How would run black pipe vertically in a wall? There isn't enough headroom in the attic to drop it through the header.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do it again?

Comment: @Daniel My worst personal experience was a minor flash burn from a balky pilot light. However, a professor of mine was killed in a gas explosion that destroyed his whole house. A local man was killed, along with his *plumber* neighbor, trying to fix a badly installed gas line.

Comment: @Daniel You may have to open the wall and then repair it. It sounds annoying, but doing it right is often just as fast and may avoid the unexpected glitches that can come up when you try to take short cuts.

Comment: The reason I ask is a local plumber who is a licensed LP installer gave me a quote and he intends to use 3/4" CSST throughout (except possibly for the straight run in the attic). He said it's coated black and much higher quality than the yellow stuff you find at Lowe's.

Comment: @Daniel I haven't seen this, but I am not a plumber. Even if heavy duty corrugated is now acceptable, I would still call in a pro.

Comment: I am _most likely_ going to do that. But one of my reasons for asking is to be better informed to discuss this with and ultimately choose a pro.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel, I will also add to the suggestions of hiring a professional. Run solid pipe though the walls. It will have to be cut the right lenght, threaded, and then assembled in place. The threads need sealant. The whole thing will be pressure tested (preferably overnight). Codes require things like a cut off valve near the appliance. With black pipe in the wall, you don't have to worry as much about poking a hole in it with a nail or screw.  A pro may have a better idea about where to route the line. Is the line already in the attic or are you running a new line from outside? If from outside, why go up to the attic and not straight throught the wall?

Answer (score 1):

The CSST (corrugated stainless steel tubing) is approved as a drop and in concealed stud cavities; however, the manufacturer's installation instruction regarding protecting the piping in the stud cavity needs to be followed.  Usually strip wound conduit is required for 12" from locations that secure the csst (terminations and penetration at the top or bottom plates).

Removing and repairing the drywall is the best solution and then running sch. 40 steel pipe in the wall and use the csst for the run to the tie-in.

Answer (score 0):

Although this was posted years ago, I figure DIYers still read through this today. If you're not a licensed professional, read through Home-Flex's Installation manual, it is free online. Essentially, there are protective barriers available now, such as striker plates and protective conduits for installation in a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Always use solid pipe in walls. And, for safety, always pressurize the line with air, seal, and make sure the pressure is maintained for a couple of days before hooking up any combustible gas.